# Rails 5, thinking sphinx, indexing and searching has meny through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a Rails App in which I want to use Thinking Sphinx for search. I have a has many though relationship between the following models, `Product` has many `Type`s through `ProductType`.

```
# Product.rb
has_many :product_types
has_many :types, through: :product_types

# Type.rb
has_many :product_types
has_many :products, through: :product_types

# ProductType.rb
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :type
```

In my `ProductsController` index action I want to be able to filter which products are shown in the view based on given `Variant` ids.

My relevant indexes currently looks like this (note, I haven't used ThinkingSphinx in a long time):

```
# product_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, :with => :active_record do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  indexes brand.name, as: :brand, sortable: true

  indexes product_types.type.id, as: :product_types

  has created_at, updated_at
end

# type_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :type, :with => :active_record do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
end

# product_type_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product_type, :with => :active_record do
  has product_id, type: :integer
  has type_id, type: :integer
end
```

I currently pass an array of `:product_types` ids in a `link_to`, like this (let me know if there is a better way to do it):

```
= link_to "Web shop", products_path(product_types: Type.all.map(&:id), brand: Brand.all.map(&:id)), class: "nav-link"
```

In my `ProductsController` I try to filter the result based on the given `Type` ids like this:

```
product_types = params[:product_types]
@products = Product.search with_all: { product_types: product_types.collect(&:to_i) }
```

When I run `rake ts:rebuild` I get the following error:

```
indexing index 'product_type_core'...
ERROR: index 'product_type_core': No fields in schema - will not index
```

And when I tries to view the view in the browser I get the following error:

```
index product_core: no such filter attribute 'product_types' 
- SELECT *   FROM `product_core` WHERE `sphinx_deleted` = 0 AND  
`product_types` = 1 AND   `product_types` = 2 AND `product_types` = 3 
LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META
```

Any ideas in how to properly set up my indexes (and query) for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues to note here:

Firstly, the error you're seeing during `rake ts:rebuild` is pointing out that you've not set any fields in your ProductType Sphinx index - no `indexes` calls for text data you wish to search on. Are you actually searching on ProductType at all? If so, what text are you expecting people to match by?

If you're not searching on that model, there's no need to have a Sphinx index for it.

Secondly, the issue with your search - you're filtering on `product_types` with integers, which makes sense. However, in your index, you've defined `product_types` as a field (using `indexes`) rather than an attribute (using `has`). Given it's integer values and you're likely not expecting someone to type in an ID into a search input, you'll almost certainly want this to be an attribute instead - so change the `indexes` to a `has` for that line in your Product index definition, and run `ts:rebuild`.

Comment: Thanks @pat! I have updated my index to look like this: `has product_types.type.id, as: :type_ids`. I found your advanced search example on [Github](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx-examples), and I've tried to do somethings similar. The relevant part of my search currently looks like this: `@products = Product.search params[:query], with_all: options[:with_all]`, `options[:with_all]` looks like this: `{:type_ids=>[2, 3]}`. But I always get 0 results: `SELECT * FROM 'product_core' WHERE 'sphinx_deleted' = 0 AND 'type_ids' = 2 AND 'type_ids' = 3 LIMIT 0, 20`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Just to confirm: are you expecting to get all products that are connected to *both* type id 2 and type id 3? (Rather than products that are connected to either one but not necessarily both). Also, it's not shown in the code you've shared, but are you translating `params[:product_types]` to Type instances at some point?

Comment: No, I want all products that have either type 1 or 3.  I have changed that bit with `params[:product_types]` from my original question. I have changed it to: `options = {:with_all => {}}`, `options[:with_all][:type_ids] = params[:filter][:type].keys.map(&:to_i)` (results in `{:type_ids=>[2, 3]}` and `@products = Product.search params[:query], with_all: options[:with_all]`, I can update my question with the updated code later. Thanks for your help @pat!

Comment: For this filter, you'll want to use `:with` rather than `:with_all`. Also, you'll want to make sure your attribute name matches what you're filtering on (have you got it set to `type_ids` in your index definition?)